# Is it legal for an HOA to require information on an owner's guests?

Tags: hoa

My HOA recently began requiring that overnight guests sign an authorization form wherein they must give their full name, relationship to the owner, phone number and photo ID.

This is a gross violation of privacy. Is it legal for an HOA to demand these things of an owner's guest?

Comment: In what jurisdiction?

Comment: New York City (Manhattan)

Comment: Is it a condominium or a co-op?

Comment: It is a condominium

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the HOA duly adopted the rule that requires this disclosure, probably yes.

An HOA is not subject to the privacy law or constitutional restrictions of a governmental entity, an HOA is the *de facto* owner of the common areas of the HOA, and in general, a private property owner can insist on getting any information the private property owner wishes as a condition of using a private property owner's property.

Generally speaking, however, the declarations of a condominium set forth the process by which rules like this one can be adopted and those rules have to be followed for the rule to be valid.